# Console Application sem mostrar a janela do console

Tags: c#, console

Possuo um Console Application na qual utilizo para rodar rotinas do meu sistema. Estou executando este console a partir do Agendador de tarefas, toda a vez que é executado, ele pisca na tela. Abre, executa o processo e fecha. Eu não quero que apareça o console na tela, quero apenas que execute.

Como faço isso?

Obs.: A aplicação precisa ser um Console Application, então a opção de mudar as properties do PROJ para Windows Application está fora de questão.

Comment: Porque não cria um serviço do windows?

Comment: Esse link é interessante. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3571628/4190610

Comment: @Marconi A empresa necessita que seja um Console app

Comment: @jbueno Já testei o exemplo teste link, e mesmo assim o Console pisca na tela.

Comment: @JonathanBarcela Entendi.

Comment: @JonathanBarcela porque a empresa necessidade isto? Estes requisitos parecem ser artificiais.

Comment: @bigown Não acho que as necessidades interfiram na resolução do problema, mas vamos lá. Estou tentando fazer o que me foi passado, criar um console application para a execução das rotinas administrativas do sistema. Este Console app será utilizado por outro sistema, que monitora essas rotinas(em mais de um módulo) no qual pega exceções, etc... que são mostradas na sala de controle. Por este motivo ele não pode ser um serviço e também necessita rodar em background.

Comment: Você pode recompilar o código e mudar pra *Windows Forms application*?

Comment: @JonathanBarcela Importa porque toda a solução está errada.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Como citado na pergunta, não. :/

Comment: @bigown Tenho que trabalhar com as ferramentas que me são disponibilizadas, infelizmente.

Comment: @JonathanBarcela neste caso não tem porque você vai criar a aplicação, pode criar do jeito que quiser. Mas tudo bem, quer fazer gambi, faça,

Comment: Isto é estranho e bem confuso :( - O que você acha que difere no resultado final o *Windows Forms application* do *Console* pra você?

Comment: Não piscar o console também é um requisito? Se for, parece que estão pedindo coisas incompatíveis. Não tem alguém na empresa com quem você possa debater esse assunto?

Comment: Acho que o problema está na pergunta. O problema real não é a aplicação ter a janela, mas sim de como fazer o agendador executar sem mostrar esta janela. Já tentou a opção de "executar escondido" do agendador? http://i.stack.imgur.com/lsued.jpg Alternativamente, agende com `cmd /c start /min SEUAPP`, nao é a mesma coisa que escondido, mas fica minimizado na Taskbar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conforme as respostas que encontrei no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2763669/1518921) você pode tentar:

1. FreeConsole:

   ```
   [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
   public static extern bool FreeConsole();
   ```
2. Usar `ProcessStartUpInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;`

   ```
   public static void main(string[] args)
   {
      Process p = new Process("MyApp");
      ProcessStartUpInfo pinfo = new ProcessStartUpInfo();
      p.StartupInfo = pinfo;
      pinfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
      pinfo.ShellExecute = false;

      p.RaiseEvents = true;

      AutoResetEvent wait = new AutoResetEvent(false);
      p.ProcessExit += (s,e)=>{ wait.Set(); };

      p.Start();
      wait.WaitOne();
   }
   ```
3. Como alternativa você pode compilar *Windows Forms application*, entendo pouco de .net, mas até aonde sei isto pouco implica na execução e para o seu caso parece ser uma boa saída.

Comment: @MarcosRegis Só um exemplo é com *Windows Forms Application* e o AP não justificou o motivo de não poder usar tal. Veja que eu citei 3 exemplos, sendo que o segundo é alternativo e a minha resposta vai além do AP, ela tem a intenção de ajudar outras pessoas com a mesma duvida e que não tenham este problema com *Windows Forms Application* :) Espero que entenda a minha justificativa

Answer (score 1):

O Console ou o Windows Forms, são projetos que esperam uma interação do usuário. Como a tarefa que você precisa executar não depende de interação, pois você está tentando ocultar o Console. É recomendável que você utilize um serviço.

Ou utilize:

```
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
 static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

 const int SW_HIDE = 0;
 const int SW_SHOW = 5;
```

---

```
 var handle = GetConsoleWindow();

 // Hide
 ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);

 // Show
 ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOW);
```

Answer (score -1):

Usa WidnowsService para essas rotinas, o Serviço será instalado no seu servidor ou maquina e ficará rodando em segundo plano, nem precisa de disparador, você coloca todas essas informações no Timer dentro do projeto.

Answer (score -2):

Voce deve executar a tarefe em uma conta diferente da que o usuário está logado. Assim nada vai aparecer.

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/47358)

Comment: @jbueno eu entendo que é uma resposta, e está 100% correta. Porém, fica a sugestão ao lsalamon de elaborar melhor o texto explicando ao menos como é que o usuário deve proceder para executar uma tarefa como um usuário diferente, para evitar a remoção por baixa qualidade. No [Superuser](http://superuser.com/a/531667/52650) tem uma resposta similar, porém elaborada.

Comment: Como assim cara, não responde a pergunta do cara

Comment: @CypherPotato *Pergunta:* "**Eu não quero que apareça o console na tela**, quero apenas que execute. Como faço isso?" - *Resposta:* **"Execute usando outra conta e nada vai aparecer"**. Me explique, por favor, como isso não responde.

Comment: Isso não é uma resposta favorável, o usuário especificou a tag **C#** na pergunta, então compreendemos que ele queria uma resposta em C#, essa resposta se quer não tem um código, apenas como oculta a janela.

Comment: @CypherPotato Concordo, mas é por isso que estão dizendo que o *problema está na pergunta*. Ele tem como requisitos ser uma aplicação de console e ao mesmo tempo iniciar e completar a execução sem que o console apareça se quer uma vez. Isso deve ser resolvido pelo sistema operacional. Se fosse para ser resolvido no código, ele teria que aceitar a possibilidade da aplicação não ser de console, não acha?

Comment: É, tem isso também, então se ele colocasse que queria em código seria outra história...

Comment: Talvez a tag c# tenha feito algumas pessoas (assim como eu) pensarem que a resposta esta incorreta, sendo que na verdade pode estar correta sim. Mas evitemos discussões aqui, esta resposta já esta sendo discutida no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4559/3635 - participem! @CypherPotato

Answer (score -3):

É Simples você tem que ir em Projeto --> Propriedades de ConsoleApp1 --> Aplicativo --> Tipo de saída e selecionar Aplicativo do Windows.

Comment: pelo que entendi da OBS que ele adicionou à pergunta, tornar o projeto _Windows Application_ não é viável.